# C# UWP Windows 10 CustomDialog: How do you show as Modeless? I can't let it freeze the info behind.

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, customdialog, modeless

If there is no Modeless option(?) is there another way to make a small movable informational Dialog/Window/Page on top of my page.  I need to keep this up as a reference but have it be movable so the underlying information can be revealed.  Visual Studio 2015, Future Store App.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the standard dialog modeless. To achieve what you want you should use a custom panel on top of your page with manipulation events hooked up to it. For example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <!-- some other content -->

    <Grid x:Name="Dialog" Background="Red" Width="200" Height="100" 
          ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="Dialog_OnManipulationDelta">

        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="DialogTransform" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And code behind:

```
 private void Dialog_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs args)
 {
     DialogTransform.TranslateX += args.Delta.Translation.X;
     DialogTransform.TranslateY += args.Delta.Translation.Y;
 }
```

Then you can build more complicated logic like show/hide animations, close buttons, etc.

Comment: That works great.  Now is there a way to get back my select capability in a contained TextBox?   I go to select text and the box moves around the display instead. New to using OnManipulationDelta.

Comment: private   void OnTextBoxMainipulation(object sender,Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogTransform.TranslateX-= e.Delta.Translation.X ;
            DialogTransform.TranslateY-=e.Delta.Translation.Y; 
        }

Comment: Turns out this can also be done with a multiple view page.  I am getting the bugs out of this but the code is on:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185575/how-get-different-size-windows-in-uwp-multiple-views