# How to set a different size windows in UWP Multiple Views?

Tags: uwp

I have tried the code in [How get different size windows in UWP Multiple Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185575/how-get-different-size-windows-in-uwp-multiple-views), but I found a problem.

The new windows size must depend on the current windows size, which means if I use

`newAppView.TryResizeView(new Size { Width = 300, Height = 200 });`

does not work.

But use

`newAppView.TryResizeView(new Size { Width = rect.Width - 300, Height = rect.Height - 200 });`

works.

Then how to set a new window size, ignoring current window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that setting the window size is invalid, but that the values you set for `Width` and `Height` are not in the valid range.

Default:

- Min Width: 500
- Min Height: 320

As long as either `Width` or `Height` is below the minimum value, the window cannot be resized.

Comment: Got it. I used `SetPreferredMinSize`method, so I can set any size.